# c# (.NET): Large Generation 2 Heap with 93% free space and 100% fragmentation

Tags: c#, .net, memory, garbage-collection, heap-memory

the current program I wrote have a very high memory usage like a memory leak. This is observable with help of Nagios. If the memory is very high and the program run very slow I get a memory dump via Windows task manager and analyse it with help of JetBrains dotMemory (External size is ca. 1 GB). Here I see a real usage of ca. 73 MB and a memory usage of generation 2 Heap of 660MB (!), 616 MB are marked as free and 42 MB are in use. The fragmentation is 100%. 
I know I cannot influence managed memory and the GC should be cleanup the memory automatically. There are any things to consider to solve this problem?

The program is a C# .NET standalone application, build with Visual Studio 2015 and .NET 4.6 in mode "Any CPU". I belive that the .NET framework on the target machine is an other version but how can I get the current installed and used version of .NET runtime?

If you need any other information please ask me for :)

**UPDATE**

The program is a machine control system that communicate with a SPS via OPC, contains a database access to an Orcale database and a lot of web services for communication with other bordered systems.

**UPDATE**

Here is the image of memory usage from dotMemory:
[image]

Comment: youre going to need to show us some code for us to be able to help you

Comment: Then look at the scope of things and check you clean up after yourself and dont leave the GC to do half the work.. eg dont create connections and leave them open or such

Comment: I cannot show the code cause the program is very very big with more than hundert classes and more than 10.000 lines of code. Cause I do not know where the problem is I cannot post a code snipped. Sorry.

Comment: @BugFinder: You mean I should run the GC manually with GC.Collect() function and FORCE flag? This is a legitimately way?

Comment: You will need to run some memory profiling tool and check which kind of objects are causing this fragmentation, if possible. I can see for sure that if you cannot narrow down the problem, then at best we can say "good luck" and come with general tips that may or may not help. If your large-object heap is fragmented, look for big objects, arrays and lists are typical culprits.

Comment: As you've not really even indicated what your app is doing, its more a case of null the things you dont need, close things you open, watch how you pass items about ..

Comment: Please note the update

Comment: Are you disposing all objects that can be disposed, when you're done with them?

Comment: The problem is not really a memory leak cause the most memory is free. That is the problem. The real used bytes are always the same, in small and in big memory dumps.

Comment: Please see the uploaded image of memory usage

Comment: if you cannot show the code, the mystic code fixing service is currently closed

Comment: In the LOH are XML artefact strings from machines objects (containing individual information about it) with size of 500 KB.

Comment: What is the context between LOH and Generation 2 Heap?

Comment: Yes of curse. But is it really the problem that the generation 2 memory has 616MB (93%) free not used areas?

Answer (score 3):

I see a lot of pinned objects (red regions). They are preventing to defragment heaps where they located. Run dotMemory with /internal command line key, there will appear "Pinned objects" link on Heap Fragmentation control, there you can see what objects are pinned.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, this is perhaps a cause for the problem. The pinned objects in gen2 are byte arrays used by System.Net objects like AsyncRequestContext / OverlappedData. But with an other tool I see a lot of objects are queued for finalization but not complete destroyed. DotMemory shows this as free space, other tools shows this as queued finalizable objects.